# Next tag badge click area is larger than a tag

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges

In the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) you can select next tag badge to track.

> [image: next]

By clicking on tag you can see a popup window with description. But this clicking area is really larger then I expected, i.e. you can mis-click over badge and popup window still will appear.

> [image: toolarge]

Moreover, when you click on the gear icon to select another tag badge, popup description window will apper too.

> [image: gear]

After clicking on gear:

> [image: too much windows]

Comment: So at a place where there is no need to click on, except when you fail to click the tag button, will give you the action you actually wanted? That is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @PatrickHofman did you mean that clicking near **any** button should interpreted as click on that button?