# Wrong x-position for next tag popup

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, tag-badges

Looks like the x-position of the popup for next tag is wrongly calculated in the [user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity):

> [image: popup]

Popup’s `^` part should be anywhere under the tag, not the outside of it. It was fine before, you can see an image from the my old post [Next tag badge click area is larger than a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292031/339911)

Comment: Congratulation for your 500th question.

Comment: @Arulkumar wow ... I did not even notice. By the way, already 501 like levi's jeans :)